# StencilJS component ReferenceError: "module is not defined" error in Firefox when adding third party script

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

I have an issue with a component in Firefox. I tested in pretty much all browsers, Safari, Opera, Brave, Chrome … only Firefox Quantum 66.0.3 (64-bit)  has problems.

The code I provided is a basic version of the whole component. The error I get is `ReferenceError: "module is not defined"` and `TypeError: "jQuery(...).setsameheight is not a function"`. (jQuery is also loaded by script.js) when running Stencil locally with `npm start --es5`. I really don’t know what else to try.

The script is required for the project, it can't be edited.

I am using `“@stencil/core”: “0.18.0"`, as a component builder. I also tried with `“@stencil/core”: “~0.16.2"`

```
import { Component, Prop, State, Element } from '@stencil/core';
import * as SCRIPT from '../../assets/script.js';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  tag: 'events',
  shadow: false
})

export class Events {

  @Element() private element: HTMLElement;

  componentDidLoad() {
    SCRIPT
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
      const elements = this.element.querySelectorAll('div.fluid')
      for (let element of elements) {
        jQuery(element).setsameheight()
      }
    }

}
```

The ReferenceError points here `community-component.core.pf.js:2485:7`

```
function execBundleCallback(bundleId, deps, callback) {
    var bundleExports = {};
    try {
      callback.apply(null, deps.map(function(d) {
        if ('exports' === d) return bundleExports;
        if ('require' === d) return userRequire;
        return getLoadedBundle(d);
      }));
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e); //line 2485
    }
```

Comment: Is `setsameheight()`  a jQuery `inbuilt` function?

Comment: No. It's part of the script that needs to be loaded.

Comment: @Ciprain - which script?

Comment: This one -> `import * as SCRIPT from '../../assets/script.js';`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `'../../assets/script.js'` is not getting loaded in `firefox`. To make `import` statement work, you need to set `dom.moduleScripts.enabled` to `true`.

See - https://starbeamrainbowlabs.com/blog/article.php?article=posts/260-es6-features-14-modules.html as well as `Browser compatibility` from section - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

[image]

Comment: So does FF come with modules riots disabled by default? I can do that for myself, but I can't ask users to do that :) Are ther5a y workarounds?

Comment: @Ciprian - Did you tried doing this change? Does it work?

Comment: I'm going to try when I get to work. Sorry ... Didn't click on the link.

Comment: <script type="module" src="./js/index.js"></script> ... Is this what you had in mind? I use Stencil just as components. Not as an app.

Comment: I don't really have any idea. I would insist you to first try the solution. Once you know why this problem is occurring you can find different ways to handle it.